# Nodejs support ECMAScript2015?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I would like understand some things, maybe someone can help-me i go
ask    my doubts to topics.

- If i to want to use new features of ECMAScript2015 in my backend code    with nodejs,this is supported.
- What i need to make for this be possible.
- The babel is one transpiller only to frontend.
- I can to use it as dependence in node_modules or the nodejs plataform    alredy is compatible with ECMAScript2015.

Comment: See http://node.green for a table of supported functionality per version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the features of ES 2015 is supported by the newest Node.js already:

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node65

Check this table out :)